# TFS 2015 npm behind a proxy

Tags: npm, tfs-2015

Recently my team started to automate our builds and releases. We got `npm install` to work but that required a to run a http-proxy command that have my username and password showing.

I tried to run npm under NetworkService Account behind a proxy, but with no luck.

Is there any way to connect without my username and password?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this `npm adduser` command to create or verify a username in the specified registry, and save the credentials to the .npmrc file. This doesn't need to enter username and password again.

**npm adduser**: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/adduser

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Only thing now is that I have to remember to change the password every 6 months or so. Company's password policy.

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi is there any feedback about this?

Comment: Yeah, didnt work. What I found out was How to set the agent to run as proxy

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi maybe you could refer to this blog: https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

In response to your initial question - Are you using TFS?  I'd suggest you use the TFS (or equivalent) service account instead of the NetworkService account.

We've been going throught the same ordeal and if you're trying to deploy a web application I'd strongly suggest that you not rely on the node_modules to be restored on build.  Instead, use WebPack to bundle up your node_modules and use them instead.
It's an extra dev-step, but well worth it as you won't get "future package version" surprises when re-deploying, and also it speeds up the build process by not requiring the download of node_modules that aren't required.

Hope it helps.